# Раскрывающийся список из базы данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток!
Вот пытаюсь сделать выпадающий список в который бы подгружались данные с БД... а написаный код не работает... подскажите пожалуйста что не так.

```
<SELECT NAME="а"> <?   
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wayflag` WHERE `rn` = '".$_GET['rn']."' ORDER              BY `atitle`",$link);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
do  
{ 
printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",$myrow["obj"],$myrow["atitle"]);
}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Не работает" - понятие растяжимое. Что именно не так? Какую ошибку выдает?
Попробуйте глобальную переменную **$_GET['rn']** перевести в обычну до запроса и  написать таким макаром:

```
$rn = $_GET['rn'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wayflag` WHERE `rn` = '$rn' ORDER BY  `atitle`",$link);
echo '<select name="а">';
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",$myrow["obj"],$myrow["atitle"]);
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!!!
С помощью его нашел где "собака зарыта":) - не то поле передавал (Вывод- вредно работать по ночам!)